# how to solve $\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I saw this problem
$$\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}dx$$
I checked wolfram and the answer is  $$\arctan\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)+C$$
but I want a method of the solution so it can help me to solve similar problems

Comment: Hint: Divide numerator and denominator by $x^2$

Comment: how do you know this would work? I mean what kind of pattern do you recognise to do that  ?

Comment: It's all about experience and intuition. Yes, it is very difficult to think of this trick or substitution normally, but after running into at least one problem implementing it, then the trick becomes yours. (These kinds of) Integration is all about experiencing various problems and techniques, adding to your 'toolbox'. Hence, there is no reason of asking 'how do you know that would work in the first place?' imo. Adding this trick into your toolbox is what really matters.

Comment: How do you know trig substitution will work on things like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, etc ? You try it out and see how it goes. It's the same thing with rational functions like this. Don't like the degrees? Make the degrees what you want them to be then

Comment: My first intuition to rational integrands would be to use partial fractions.

Edit: I asked Wolframalpha to split this integrand into partial fractions, and it got ugly and involved complex numbers lol.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi sorry but I couldn't  figure out what to do after your hint

Comment: @Ahmed I posted the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I = \int \frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{4} - x^{2} + 1} dx = \int \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}} - 1} dx$$

Let $u = x - \frac{1}{x}$ then $du = (1 + \frac{1}{x^{2}}) dx$ and

$$\begin{aligned} I = \int \frac{1}{u^{2} + 1} du &= \arctan(u) + C \\ &= \arctan \left( \frac{x^{2} - 1}{x} \right) + C \end{aligned}$$

Using the fact that $\arctan(x) + \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, we can check that it matches Wolfram's answer. Using partial fractions is possible, but it is very dirty and not recommended since the denominator has only non-real zeros.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Beside the elegant solution given by @Vue, just write
$$\frac {x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}=\frac {x^2+1}{(x^2-a)(x^2-b)}$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition, the integrand is just
$$\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{a+1}{x^2-a}-\frac{b+1}{x^2-b}\right)$$ and integration leads to
$$\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{(b+1) \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}}\right)}{\sqrt{b}}-\frac{(a+1) \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\right)$$

Using now the fact that
$$a=\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$ replace, simplify the complex numbers  to obtain
$$\int\frac {x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\,dx=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2} \left(1-i \sqrt{3} \right)\right)+\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3} \right)\right)$$ and now
$$\tan^{-1}(A)+\tan^{-1}(B)=\cdots\cdots$$

The advantage of this is that you can apply it to any polynomial denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Substitute $x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$ to get a simpler integral,

$$\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1} \, dx \\
&= - \int \frac{\frac{1-y}{1+y}+1}{\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}-\frac{1-y}{1+y}+1} \, \sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \\
&= -2 \int \frac{dy}{\left(3y^2+1\right)\sqrt{1-y^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

I decided to visit my old questions to see If I could solve them now

$$I:= \int \frac{x^2 +1}{x^4 -x^2 +1} dx =  \int \frac{x^2 +1}{(x^2+1)^2 -3x^2} dx=\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1) -3\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right) } dx $$

let $x=\tan(t) $ $dx = \sec^2(t) dt $
$$I = \int \frac{\sec^2(t)}{\sec^2(t) -3\left( 1-\frac{1}{\sec^2(t)}\right) } dt= \int \frac{\sec^2(t)}{\sec^2(t) -3 \sin^2(t) } dt=\int \frac{1}{1 - \frac{3}{4}\sin^2(2t) } dt$$ $$  = \int \frac{1}{ \cos^2(2t)+ \frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2t) } dt= \int \frac{2* \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(2t)}{ 1+ \frac{1}{4}\tan^2(2t) } dt = \arctan \left( \frac{\tan(2t)}{2} \right) +C  $$

since $\tan(2t) =\frac{2 \tan(t)}{ 1-\tan^2(t)} $ and since $tan(t)=x$ then $\tan(2t) =\frac{2 x}{ 1-x^2} $

so that
$$I =\arctan \left( \frac{\tan(2t)}{2} \right) +C =\arctan\left( \frac{ \tan(t)}{ 1-\tan^2(t)}\right) +C=\arctan\left(\frac{ x}{ 1-x^2}  \right)+C $$